# RTMPS, how to implement it

Tags: ssl-certificate, red5, rtmp, rtmps

m pretty new to this `SSL` stuff. I am trying to implement `RTMPS with SSL certificates`. Whenever i m trying to get these properties of `RTMPS`. My eclipse gives me an error log.

```
    <property name="eventThreadsCore" value="${rtmp.event_threads_core}" />
    <property name="eventThreadsMax" value="${rtmp.event_threads_max}" />
    <property name="eventThreadsQueue" value="${rtmp.event_threads_queue}" />
    <property name="eventThreadsKeepalive" value="${rtmp.event_threads_keepalive}" />
```

- The error log is as follows :

`[WARN] [main] org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor - Invalid JavaBean property 'enableMinaMonitor' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableMinaMonitor(java.lang.String)]: [public void org.red5.server.jmx.JMXAgent.setEnableMinaMonitor(boolean)] [INFO] [main] org.red5.server.service.WarDeployer - War deployer service created [INFO] [main] org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@4a93837b: startup date [Thu Oct 27 09:08:00 PKT 2011]; parent: ApplicationContext 'red5.common' [INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer -Loading properties file from class path resource [red5.properties] [INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@621bedb0: defining beans [customEditorConfigurer,placeholderConfig,rtmpMinaConnManager,rtmpHandler,rtmpMinaIoHandler,rtmpTransport,rtmpMinaConnection,rtmptConnManager,rtmptHandler,rtmptServlet,rtmptConnection,rtmpsMinaIoHandler,rtmpsTransport,debugProxyIoHandler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@75a9883d [INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@12746ad0: defining beans [placeholderConfig,red5.common,red5.core,context.loader,pluginLauncher,tomcat.server]; root of factory hierarchy [INFO] [main] org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Closing ApplicationContext 'red5.common': startup date [Thu Oct 27 09:07:59 PKT 2011]; root of context hierarchy [INFO] [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@75a9883d: defining beans [placeholderConfig,red5.server,jmxFactory,jmxAgent,serializer,deserializer,statusObjectService,rtmpCodecFactory,rtmptCodecFactory,remotingCodecFactory,streamableFileFactory,filePersistenceThread,sharedObjectService,streamService,providerService,consumerService,bandwidthFilter,schedulingService,warDeployService,remotingClient,object.cache,keyframe.cache,flv.impl,flvreader.impl,mp4reader.impl,mp3reader.impl,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean#1,streamExecutor,playlistSubscriberStream,clientBroadcastStream]; root of factory hierarchy Bootstrap complete org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'red5.core' defined in class path resource [red5.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'rtmpsTransport' defined in class path resource [red5-core.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.event_threads_core' at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:283) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:886) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416) at org.red5.server.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:62) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:135) at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:50) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'rtmpsTransport' defined in class path resource [red5-core.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.event_threads_core' at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:107) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275) ... 18 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'rtmpsTransport' defined in class path resource [red5-core.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.event_threads_core' at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:272) at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:75) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:599) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:398) at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140) at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:106) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126) ... 20 more`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all here..

```
 Invalid bean definition with name 'rtmpsTransport' defined in class path resource [red5-core.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'rtmp.event_threads_core' at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
```

for the time being just comment out those and ur code will be good to go. I dont think u need them in latest red5 also the basic class for them is different and u can see it way down the `red5-core.xml` file.